# The difference in meaning between "There is no student who... " and "There was no student who... "?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 1. There is no student who did not bring his or her ID cards to the examination hall.
> 2. There was no student who did not bring his or her ID cards to the examination hall.

I'd like to know the difference in meaning of the two sentences.

Comment: This is a complex sentence because of the double negatives. That problem could be eliminated using "failed to". "There is no student who failed to bring their ID card to the examination hall."

Comment: _Is_ is present, _was_ is past tense. So the first sentence describes a current situation, the second one something that was true _in the past_. Basically, the same thing you always do with verb tenses.

Comment: The fact that the who-clause is in the past tense in both sentences might make them confusing.  They might have been clearer with perfects, "who has not brought" and "who had not brought".